# Minimization over function space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, convex-optimization

This is the first time I encounter a problem where I need to minimize a function defined in a function space. Define the function space $A=\{\theta:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow\mathbb{R}|\ \theta\ \text{is continuous}\}$. Let $h:A→\mathbb{R}$ be a function which we want to minimize (optimization). What conditions do we need on $A$ and $h$ if we want to have that the solution $argmin_{f\in A}h(f)$ has bounded partial derivatives? I have no idea how to approach this problem.

Comment: Search for calculus of variations.

Comment: Jules gave th right buzzword. In fact, this can be tricky and the regularity of minimizers is usually the third step (after showing existence and/or uniqueness which are both not obvious in many cases).

Comment: I can put regularity conditions on h.